# Can I debug code using already created objects - Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have some code that performs heavy computations in script1.py. I ran it already (send to Python console with Alt+Shift+e) and have all objects created, stored in memory. Now I'm developing my code further (in script2.py that calls script1.py at the very beginning) but there's error I need to investigate. I wanted to use Pycharm Debugger, on the part of code so I marked this part of script.py, clicked with the right mouse button and run Debug script2.py. But it seems to run all the code included so I have to re-run all the computations from script1.py which is totally cumbersome. Is there a way to run the debugger with already created objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to save the object in your first script then load the pickled object in your second script.

**script1.py**

```
# Save a dictionary into a pickle file.
import pickle

favorite_color = {"first": "yellow", "second": "red"}

pickle.dump(favorite_color, open("save.p", "wb"))
```

**script2.py**

```
# Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.
import pickle

favorite_color = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
# favorite_color is now {"first": "yellow", "second": "red"}
```